# extjs function declaration syntax

Tags: extjs

In extjs, we often have syntax like this:

```
someFunction = function(){}
```

or:

```
someFunction : function(){}
```

What is the difference between the two? Also, what enables exts to use this syntax as opposed to the normal javascript syntax? 
So far as i know, javascript syntax is like this:

function(){}//No '=' or ':'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is not ExtJS function syntax. All these methods of defining a function are part of JavaScript and there is nothing new introduced by ExtJS. Lets take each case

1. function functionname() - 
   This is most common and is coming from the procedural programming school. Basically you are writing global functions and these are called by other functions in your script

Enter OOP in Javascript.. there is where the next two methods come in! Javascript is very flexible and extensible. Functions can be stored in variables, passed into other
functions as arguments, passed out of functions as return values, and constructed at run-time. You can also have anonymous functions! coming back...

1. someFunction = function() - In this case, you are storing a function in the variable 'comeFunction'.This variable can be part of an object or separate (But internally everything in javascript is object except for primitive data types).
2. someFunction : function() - In this case also, you are storing the function in the variable but this is during object declaration. You will see them used in ExtJS because it follows OOP.

You could also inject a method or modify the method you already specified by the above two methods. I hope this helps you understand more about functions.